# Symmetric sum of $ab(3a+c)$

Tags: summation, summation-method

I'm having difficulty with determining the $\sum_{sym}ab(3a+c)$ involving $3$ variables $a,b,c$. I know the cyclic sum is going to be $ab(3a+c)+bc(3b+a)+ac(3c+b)$, but I'm confused about the symmetric sum. Please include all the terms that are going to get added so I get how we are permuting the variables and how each term would look like. Thanks.

Comment: $ba(3b+c)+cb(3c+a)+ac(3a+b).$

Comment: @AnneBauval that is including the 3 terms from the cyclic sum right?

Comment: Yes, $|S_3|=6$ terms alltogether.

Comment: Why is this question silently down-voted? An explanation should've been given to a new user who made an honest attempt.